# random number from a IQueryable

Tags: c#

I have a method like this: it is a list of BSN numbers. And I need to have a random number of it.

```
    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
            {
                return Repository.GetAll();
            }

 public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            return _dbSet;
        }
```

and from this list of numbers I want to get a random number from this list.

I try it like this:

```
   Random rnd2 = new Random();
     var Banners = HelperManager.LeraarReposHelper.GetAll();//.Where(p => 
     p.PersoonId != 1).OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(3);
     int index = rnd2.Next(0, Banners.Count() - 1);

    Verwijzing = Banners.ToString()
```

But this doesn't work.

So how to archieve this?

Thank you.

if I do it like this:

```
 var Banners = HelperManager.LeraarReposHelper.GetAll().Where(p => p.PersoonId != 1).OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(1);
```

I get this error:

```
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at VLR.TestData.Repository.UnitOfWork.SaveChanges() in E:\Projects\Source\Repos\EndToEndTest\VLR.TestData.Repository\UnitOfWork.cs:line 40
   at VLR.TestData.Repository.Helpers.HelperBase`1.Insert(TEntity entity, Boolean autoSave) in E:\Projects\Source\Repos\EndToEndTest\VLR.TestData.Repository\Helpers\HelperBase.cs:line 103
   at VLR.TestData.Repository.Helpers.DBHelpers.ZaakReposHelper.Insert(Zaak zaak, Boolean autoSave) in E:\Projects\Source\Repos\EndToEndTest\VLR.TestData.Repository\Helpers\DBHelpers\ZaakReposHelper.cs:line 42
   at VLR.TestData.Generator.Processes.ZaakGenerator.CreateZaak() in E:\Projects\Source\Repos\EndToEndTest\VLR.TestData.Generator\Processes\ZaakGenerator.cs:line 72
   at VLR.TestData.Generator.Tool.Processes.ZaakProcess.Generate(Int32 size) in E:\Projects\Source\Repos\EndToEndTest\VLR.TestData.Generator.Tool\Processes\ZaakProcess.cs:line 23
```

and this is the class:

```
public partial class Leraar : EntityBase
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Leraar()
        {
            this.Bevoegdheid = new HashSet<Bevoegdheid>();
            this.DuoArbeidsovereenkomst = new HashSet<DuoArbeidsovereenkomst>();
            this.LeraarActiefStatusLog = new HashSet<LeraarActiefStatusLog>();
            this.Portfolio = new HashSet<Portfolio>();
            this.Migraties = new HashSet<Migratie>();
            this.AanbodDeelnemers = new HashSet<AanbodDeelnemer>();
            this.LeraarSchools = new HashSet<LeraarSchool>();
            this.PortfolioDoorsturen = new HashSet<PortfolioDoorsturen>();
            Initialize();
        }

        partial void Initialize();

        public int PersoonId { get; set; }
        public int WizardStap { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> RegistratieDatumUtc { get; set; }
        public bool IsGeheim { get; set; }
        public System.Guid LeraarGuid { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> MigratieVoorwaardenAkkoordDatumUtc { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> RegisterleraarGebruikerId { get; set; }
        public string RegisterleraarGebruikersnaam { get; set; }
        public string RegisterNummer { get; set; }
        public bool ToonMigratieMelding { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> VerklaringAkkoordDatumUtc { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> AanmeldDatumUtc { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Bevoegdheid> Bevoegdheid { get; set; }
        public virtual BrpPersoon BrpPersoon { get; set; }
        public virtual DuoAdresBuitenland DuoAdresBuitenland { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<DuoArbeidsovereenkomst> DuoArbeidsovereenkomst { get; set; }
        public virtual RegisterVoorportaalTermijn RegisterVoorportaalTermijn { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<LeraarActiefStatusLog> LeraarActiefStatusLog { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Portfolio> Portfolio { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Migratie> Migraties { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<AanbodDeelnemer> AanbodDeelnemers { get; set; }
        public virtual LeraarBeheer LeraarBeheer { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<LeraarSchool> LeraarSchools { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<PortfolioDoorsturen> PortfolioDoorsturen { get; set; }
    }
```

So this is the Leraar class. So how to correct this.

Thank you

So this is the class:

```
public class ZaakGenerator : DataGenerator
    {

        private BsnDataGenerator _bsnGenerator = new BsnDataGenerator();

        public ZaakGenerator(UnitOfWork unitOfWork) : base(unitOfWork)
        {
            DateTime tomorrow = DateTime.Now;
            var startDate = GetRandomDate(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3), DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5));
            var endDate = ProbabilityBool(80) ? null : (DateTime?)GetRandomDate(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), DateTime.Now.AddYears(2));
        }

        public Zaak CreateZaak()
        {
            ZaakNotitie NotitieZaak = CreateZaakNotitie();
            ZaakHistorie zaakHistory = CreateZaakHistorie();

            //int rnd = new Random();//.Next();
            Random rnd2 = new Random();


            var Banners = HelperManager.LeraarReposHelper.GetAll().Where(p => p.PersoonId != 1).OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(1).ToList();
            int index = rnd2.Next(0, Banners.Count() - 1);
            int r = rnd2.Next(Banners.Count());


            var numReviews = RandomNumber(1, 100);
            var teachers = HelperManager.LeraarReposHelper.GetAll()
                                .OrderBy(t => Guid.NewGuid())
                                .Take(numReviews)
                                .Select(t => t.PersoonId)
                                .ToList();



            DateTime datumBinnenkomst = GetRandomDate(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-18), DateTime.Now);
            var DatumAfgehandeld = ProbabilityBool(80) ? null : (DateTime?)GetRandomDate(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), DateTime.Now.AddYears(2));
            string bsn = string.Empty;
            var zaakBsn = HelperManager.LeraarReposHelper.GetByBsn(bsn);

            var zaak = new Zaak
            {
                Type = 100,
                Verwijzing = Banners.ToString(), //zaakBsn.ToString(), //_bsnGenerator.GetUniqueBSNNumberFromListZaak(), 
                Status = 103,
                Substatus = null,
                Afhandeling = 106,
                Actiehouder = 101,
                DatumBinnenkomst = datumBinnenkomst,
                DatumAfgehandeld = DatumAfgehandeld,
                Steekproef = generateZeroOrNull(),               

                ZaakNotitie = new[] { NotitieZaak },
                ZaakHistorie = new[] { zaakHistory }

            };
            HelperManager.ZaakReposHelper.Insert(zaak);

            return zaak;

        }
    }
```

This is the error message:

```
Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

ErrorMessage = "The field Verwijzing must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '16'."
```

But the BSN number is just 9 numbers long

This is the GetBsn method:

```
 public Leraar GetByBsn(string bsn)
        {
            return GetAll().FirstOrDefault(l => l.BrpPersoon.Bsn.Equals(bsn, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        }
```

But so how to get a random bsn number from the list?

Thank you.

and this is the method for GetListAll():

```
 public IList<BrpPersoon> GetListAll()
        {
            IQueryable<BrpPersoon> result = GetAll();

            result = result.Where(r => true);

            return result
                .OrderBy(r => r.Bsn)
                .ToList();
        }
```

So if I do this:

```
 public void ReturnAll33()
        {

           var hallo = HelperManager.BrpPersoonReposHelper2.GetListAll()
                .Where(p => p.Bsn != "1")
                .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
                .Take(1).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine(hallo);    

        }
```

Then I will get back:

the object, with bsn number.

But so how to return only one random bsn number?

Thank you

```
 public void ReturnAll33()
        {
            var numReviews = RandomNumber(1, 100);

            var hallo = HelperManager.BrpPersoonReposHelper2.GetListAll()
                .Where(p => p.Bsn != "1")
                .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
                .Take(numReviews)
                .Select(p => p.Bsn)
                .Take(1).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine(hallo);    

        }
```

And I get a correct random  bsn number back:
309943917.

But I get this error:

The field Verwijzing must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '16'.

when I assing the property, like this:

```
 var numReviews = RandomNumber(1, 100);

            var selectRandomBsnNumber = HelperManager.BrpPersoonReposHelper2.GetListAll()
                .Where(p => p.Bsn != "1")
                .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
                .Take(numReviews)
                .Select(p => p.Bsn)
                .Take(1).ToList();
            //


            ZaakNotitie NotitieZaak = CreateZaakNotitie();
            ZaakHistorie zaakHistory = CreateZaakHistorie();        


            DateTime datumBinnenkomst = GetRandomDate(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-18), DateTime.Now);
            var DatumAfgehandeld = ProbabilityBool(80) ? null : (DateTime?)GetRandomDate(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), DateTime.Now.AddYears(2));         


            var zaak = new Zaak
            {
                Type = 100,
                Verwijzing = selectRandomBsnNumber.ToString(), 
                Status = 103,
                Substatus = null,
                Afhandeling = 106,
                Actiehouder = 101,
                DatumBinnenkomst = datumBinnenkomst,
                DatumAfgehandeld = DatumAfgehandeld,
                Steekproef = generateZeroOrNull(),               

                ZaakNotitie = new[] { NotitieZaak },
                ZaakHistorie = new[] { zaakHistory }

            };
            HelperManager.ZaakReposHelper.Insert(zaak);
```

It looks now like this:

```
 public Zaak CreateZaak()
        {
            //select random bsn number from DB:

            var numReviews = RandomNumber(1, 100);

            var selectRandomBsnNumber = HelperManager.BrpPersoonReposHelper2.GetListAll()                
                .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
                .Take(numReviews)
                .Select(p => p.Bsn)
                .Take(1).ToArray().ToString();
            //

            foreach (var selectRandom in selectRandomBsnNumber)
            {
                selectRandom.ToString();
            }


            ZaakNotitie NotitieZaak = CreateZaakNotitie();
            ZaakHistorie zaakHistory = CreateZaakHistorie();        


            DateTime datumBinnenkomst = GetRandomDate(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-18), DateTime.Now);
            var DatumAfgehandeld = ProbabilityBool(80) ? null : (DateTime?)GetRandomDate(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), DateTime.Now.AddYears(2));
            string stringBVsn = string.Join(",", selectRandomBsnNumber.ToArray());

            var zaak = new Zaak
            {
                Type = 100,
                Verwijzing = stringBVsn.First().ToString(), //selectRandomBsnNumber.ToString(), 
                Status = 103,
                Substatus = null,
                Afhandeling = 106,
                Actiehouder = 101,
                DatumBinnenkomst = datumBinnenkomst,
                DatumAfgehandeld = DatumAfgehandeld,
                Steekproef = generateZeroOrNull(),               

                ZaakNotitie = new[] { NotitieZaak },
                ZaakHistorie = new[] { zaakHistory }

            };
            HelperManager.ZaakReposHelper.Insert(zaak);

            return zaak;
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you just `.Take(1)` instead of 3? Then you would get 1 somewhat random element.

Comment: I edit the post

Comment: You didn't include the actual exception, just the stack trace, so we can't know what the error is. Secondly, I don't think you included the code that the stack trace pointed at, the methods `ZaakGenerator.CreateZaak()` and `DBHelpers.ZaakReposHelper.Insert ` mainly.

Comment: I edit the post

Comment: ..and please also include the exception (the error message) you get.

Comment: I edit the post

Comment: You have edited the post multiple times. It is a bit unclear what the status is now. Do you still get the same exception message?

Answer (score 0):

The code you are showing is `Verwijzing = Banners.ToString()`, but `Banners` seems to be a list:

```
var Banners = HelperManager.LeraarReposHelper.GetAll()
                           .Where(p => p.PersoonId != 1)
                           .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
                           .Take(1).ToList();
```

So you try to put the `ToString` of a `List` into the `Verwijzing` property.

If I look at the last sentence of your question, it seems that you should put `bsn` into this property instead.

I don't think this has anything to do with a random number.